# Simple Javascript tax calculator

Tags: calculator, tax

I am working on a tax calculator, and i don't get it to work. The only result i get is NaN, and I can't find what's wrong with my code. If the users input is 450 000 or more, the output is supposed to be 32% of their salary else 28%.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">  
     <meta name="description" content="Skatt">
     <meta name="author" content="Gandalf">  
     <title>Taxes</title>
   </head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="salary" value="0" />
    <button id="button">Calculate tax!</button>
    <h2 id="salaryOut">Your salary is NOK:</h2>
    <h2 id="taxOut">You should pay taxes with the amount of:</h2>

<script>
    var button = document.getElementById("button");

    button.onclick = function() {

    var salary = document.getElementById("salary");
    salary.value = 0;

    var salaryOut = document.getElementById("salaryOut");
    salaryOut.value = salary;

    var salaryOut = document.getElementById("taxOut");
    taxOut.value = parseFloat(salaryOut.value);

    if(salaryOut.value<450000) {
        taxOut.value = salaryOut.value * .28;
    } 
    else {
        taxOut.value = salaryOut.value * .32;
    }
        salaryOut.innerHTML = ("Your salary is NOK: " + salary.value + ",-");   
        skattUt.innerHTML = "You should pay NOK: " + taxOut.value + ",-";
    }           
</script>   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You set `lonnUt.value = lonn;` where `lonn` is a document element, not a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're performing all of your calculations *right away* as soon as the page *loads*, when there are no actual values to calculate.  The only thing you're doing in your `click` handler is displaying the values that were already calculated.

Since there were no values to calculate when the page first loaded, that result is `NaN`.

Put all of your logic in the click handler:

```
var knapp = document.getElementById("knapp");

knapp.onclick = function() {

    var lonn = document.getElementById("lonn");

    var lonnUt = document.getElementById("lonnUt");
    var skattUt = document.getElementById("skattUt");

    var result = 0;

    if(lonn.value<450000) {
        result = lonn.value * .28;
    } 
    else {
        result = lonn.value * .32;
    }

    lonnUt.innerHTML = ("Lønnen din er kr: " + lonn.value + ",-");  
    skattUt.innerHTML = "Skatten din er kr: " + result + ",-";
}
```

That way you give the user a chance to input numbers before you try to perform calculations on those numbers.

(Note: I keep re-editing this because I'm having a *lot* of trouble deciphering the actual logic of what you're trying to do.  The variable names don't help, since I don't speak that language.  It's certainly possible that there are *other* problems here as well.  But the main one is that you need to perform the calculations *after* the user types the values, not before.)

**Edit:** I've further modified the code here after finding another significant issue.  You were trying to access a `.value` property on `h2` elements, which doesn't exist.  You were also trying to store information in those elements as though they were variables.

Instead, just declare a variable to store the result of your calculation.  Get the input (`lonn`), perform the calculation and get a result (`result`), write the output to the HTML elements (`lonnUt` and `skattUt`).

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up! But i still get the NaN,- as output in the     "skattUt.innerHTML = "Skatten din er kr: + skattUt.value + ",-";"

Comment: @Blomshit: When you step through the code in a debugger, on which specific line do you see an unexpected value?

Comment: @Blomshit: It looks like you're also trying to access a `.value` property of non-input HTML elements, which don't have such a property.  I *think* I've understood what you're trying to do and have modified the code in the answer accordingly.  Adding an explanation to the answer now...

Comment: I have translated it to english now, so it is easier for you to understand! Thank you very much for helping!